# How to calculate avrage PSNR when it contains inf values?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, video-processing, ssim

I got PSNR via VQMT, then I found some 'inf' values in the calculated csv file which I understood it means the frame in the decoded sequence is identical to the original video frame. There are also some values like 111.29. My question here is that what is the max value for PSNR before inf? because it seems 111.29 is a very high value but they are not the same! why do I have these big values?

At the end of CSV file (contains PSNR for all frames) the average PSNR is written 'inf'. My question is that how should I get the average PSNR? should I ignore the inf frames and getting the average for the rest? it is not very accure in my mind! or I should, for example, replace inf with something like 111.229 and then getting average with it?

My question here is I understand 111.229 could be the max threshold when the two frames are identical, but I can't find any reference for it, if this is right do you know any reference for it?

Comment: I think it would be better to take the average MSE across all frames, and calculate the overall PSNR with that.

Comment: In fact, I should present PSNR graph. then the average PSNR should be related to what I present. Should i remove the inf from the graph? then it doesn't show that i have some similar frames! if not, should i replace with 111.229? (is 111.229 correct? is it the max? )

Comment: If i want to get MSE which tool i can use?

Comment: ffmpeg - psnr filter. Example CLI `ffmpeg -i main -i ref -filter_complex psnr=f=stats.txt -an -f null -`. stats file will have `n,mse_avg,mse_y,mse_u,mse_v,psnr_avg,psnr_y,psnr_u,psnr_v` fields with overall result printed to stderr log.

Comment: Isn't it for mp4? i need it for yuv.

Comment: I checked with ffmpeg (with mp4) and i found it (similar to h264) is removing inf frames and get average of other frames for psnr! i am trying to check JM reference.

Comment: is there any way to calculate psnr with jm reference? I am trying to understand if jm removes inf valuse or it uses a value like 111.229 for psnr calculation